# JPA Entities and GlassFish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

Hello I'm creating simple JavaEE application. I've started with creating EJB module which has to create Databases with JPA. Problem is it cannot create these databases with Glassfish Server (without as Maven project It works)

Here is one of my entity classes:

```
package task.jpa.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
*
* @author ml
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "MODEL", schema = "KOMIS")
public class ModelDTO implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "MARKA", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String marka;
@Column(name = "NAZWA_MODELU", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String nazwaModelu;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMarka() {
    return marka;
}

public void setMarka(String marka) {
    this.marka = marka;
}

public String getNazwaModelu() {
    return nazwaModelu;
}

public void setNazwaModelu(String nazwaModelu) {
    this.nazwaModelu = nazwaModelu;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ModelDTO{" + "id=" + id + ", marka=" + marka + ", nazwaModelu=" + nazwaModelu + '}';
}
}
```

My persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>komis</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And error I have when I run it:

```
cze 13, 2015 6:46:27 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
[EL Info]: 2015-06-13 18:46:27.755--ServerSession(660017404)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
cze 13, 2015 6:46:47 PM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory createActiveResourceAdapter
SEVERE: RAR6001 : Class Not found : com.sun.gjc.spi.ResourceAdapterImpl
cze 13, 2015 6:46:47 PM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory createActiveResourceAdapter
SEVERE: 
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:111)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.createActiveResourceAdapter(ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.createActiveResourceAdapter(ConnectorRuntime.java:427)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:107)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:487)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:622)
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2015-06-13 18:46:47.286--ServerSession(660017404)--Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [komis].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'komis' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at task.jpa.util.JpaFactory.<init>(JpaFactory.java:21)
at task.jpa.util.JpaFactory.getInstanance(JpaFactory.java:26)
at task.jpa.util.JpaFactory.getEntityManager(JpaFactory.java:32)
at task.jpa.dao.GenericJpaDao.getEntityManager(GenericJpaDao.java:68)
at task.jpa.dao.GenericJpaDao.save(GenericJpaDao.java:33)
at task.jpa.base.generatorBazy.main(generatorBazy.java:34) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.gjc.spi.ResourceAdapterImpl
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:102)
... 28 more

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [komis].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'komis' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at task.jpa.util.JpaFactory.<init>(JpaFactory.java:21)
at task.jpa.util.JpaFactory.getInstanance(JpaFactory.java:26)
at task.jpa.util.JpaFactory.getEntityManager(JpaFactory.java:32)
at task.jpa.dao.GenericJpaDao.getEntityManager(GenericJpaDao.java:68)
at task.jpa.dao.GenericJpaDao.save(GenericJpaDao.java:33)
at task.jpa.base.generatorBazy.main(generatorBazy.java:34)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [komis].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'komis' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]]
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:520)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
... 13 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'komis' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:622)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
... 18 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to look up ConnectorDescriptor from JNDI [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR]
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:114)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:487)
... 22 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating active RAR
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:111)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.createActiveResourceAdapter(ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.createActiveResourceAdapter(ConnectorRuntime.java:427)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:107)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.gjc.spi.ResourceAdapterImpl
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:102)
... 28 more
Java Result: 1
```

First I had only error with Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [komis]. - then I added JDBC Resource named 'komis' in GlassFish configuration. I might have not configured it properly, so I'll be very thankful if someone could guide me to answer what is wrong.

Comment: Did you create a necessary datasource named `komis` (JNDI) in the server?

Comment: Yup. It's created.
https://i.imgur.com/vNAlrE2.png
I think it's something with Connection Pools, I'll dig into that.